# Use current argument of splat operator

Tags: ruby, arrays, splat

I have a list of car makes

```
 makes = [acura, honda, ford]
```

and I'm trying to iterate through an array of strings and find out if the individual string contains one of these makes AND if it does, to put that specific makes into an array

so I've got

```
strings.each do |string|

  if string.include?(*makes)

  else

  end
end
```

how do I use the current argument of the splat process to determine which make matched up with the string? Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** As I posted in the comments below, I'm looking for a specific make to be returned, instead of a true/false answer. So if the string is "New toyota celica", the return should be "toyota".

Comment: You could check each make individually.

Comment: There is actually 40+ makes in the real project so not an easy task! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
makes = ['acura', 'honda', 'ford']
strings = ['hyundai acura ford', 'sports car']

strings.each do |string|
  p makes.any? { |make| string.include? make }
end
```

Alternative that use regular expression: (See [`Regexp::union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union))

```
strings = ['hyundai acura ford', 'sports car']
makes = ['acura', 'honda', 'ford']
pattern = Regexp.union(makes)

strings.each do |string|
  p string.match(pattern) != nil
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
strings.each do |string|
  p makes.find { |make| string.include? make }
end
```

or

```
strings.each do |string|
  p makes.select { |make| string.include? make }
end
```

Comment: Using `String#join` here is ugly. You should use `Regexp.union`.

Comment: @sawa, Thank you for your advice. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: Interesting, question that still is open - is escaping necessary.

Comment: @sawa, According to [`Regexp` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html), it is denoted as `::union`. Actually both `Regexp::union` and `Regexp.union` are acceptable.

Comment: Not going much in to the offtopic, but on interpreter level both notations work the same, though I agree with @sawa about avoiding `::`.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons, `Regexp::union` escapes the strings. For example, `Regexp.union(['a.b', '^$'])` yields `/a\.b|\^\$/`.

Comment: @falsetru Sorry, my comment about `::` did not make sense. I removed it. And good point about automatic escape.

Comment: just ran this in ruby fiddle, these return a true or false. I'm looking for the specific make in the string. So if the string is "New toyota celica" I would check against the makes array and it would return "toyota" instead of "true". Let me know if I misunderstood your answer! I can be a bit dense sometimes.

Comment: @Kwestion, Then, try `strings.each do |string| p makes.select { |make| string.include? make } end` or `strings.each do |string| p makes.find { |make| string.include? make } end`

Comment: WORKS! Thanks for answering so quick, really helpful for a ruby n00b like me.

Answer (score 1):

If Your `makes` are not very long, then one of the shortest thing would be using Regex, as already suggested:

```
makes = ['acura', 'honda', 'ford']
strings = ['hyundai acura ford', 'sports car']
strings.grep(/#{makes.join('|')}/)

 # => ["hyundai acura ford"]
```

After a slight discussion we came up this to be one of the best choices:

```
strings.grep(Regexp.union(makes))
```

Comment: Write if you want - `makes *('|')`... :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, by intersecting arrays:

```
makes = ["acura", "honda", "ford"]

strings = [
"I own a Toyota and a Ford",
"My friend Becky loves her Acura",
"I plan to buy a BMW",
"I now have an Acura, but have had both a honda and a Ford"
]

strings.each do |s|
  a = s.scan(/(\w+)/).flatten.map(&:downcase) & makes
  puts "#{s}\n" + (a.empty? ? "  No matches" : "  Matches: #{a.join}")
end

I own a Toyota and a Ford
  Matches: ford
My friend Becky loves her Acura
  Matches: acura
I plan to buy a BMW
  No matches
I now have an Acura, but have had both a honda and a Ford
  Matches: acura honda ford
```

Note that it is necessary to use `scan` with a regex, rather than `split`, as punctuation would be a problem with the latter (e.g., 'Acura,` would not be matched).